# Can $e^{-1/zw}$ be written as a difference of holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm the teaching assistant for an undergraduate complex analysis course at my current university. I was reviewing some old prep materials to try and find some good practice problems to give to my students, and happened on the following:

> Consider $\Bbb C^2$ with coordinates $z,w$. Can the function $f=e^{-1/zw}$ be written as a difference of two functions $g,h$, where $g$ is holomorphic away from $z=0$ and $h$ is holomorphic away from $w=0$? Explain your answer.

This was at the end of some final exam prep and was marked with a (*) to indicate it was supposed to be challenging. (This was also set by a professor who has since been hired away from my institution and was known for making some, uh, *difficult* exams.) I'm interested in finding a good solution.

The best I've been able to do so far is that if $g$ and $h$ were globally represented by power series, allowing for negative exponents for $z$ in $g$ and negative exponents in $h$, then by looking at negative-degree terms in $z$ and $w$ we ought to reach a contradiction: $\frac{1}{zw}$ cannot be represented as a sum of elements of the form $\frac{p(z,w)}{z^n}$ and $\frac{q(z,w)}{w^n}$, which should lead to what we need. But this argument feels untrustworthy - I know that if a function of one variable is entire on $\Bbb C$, I can find a global power series for it, but I'm deeply unsure about generalizing that to something like $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C^\times$, and it feels like I'm not really taking full advantage of how bad the singularities of $e^{-1/zw}$ are near $zw=0$. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to consider doing $\int_{z \in C} \int_{w \in C} u(z,w) \, dw \, dz$ to everything, where $C$ is the curve going counterclockwise one time around the origin.  If you plug in $u(z,w) = e^{-1/zw}$ you get $4\pi$, and if you plug in for $u(z,w)$ a function that is either holomorphic for $z \ne 0$ or holomorphic for $w \ne 0$, you get $0$.

Comment: This looks promising. I'd like to check one bit of reasoning for one of the steps with the integral: if we integrate a function holomorphic for $w\neq 0$ on $\int_{w\in C}$, then we get something holomorphic in $z$ out, which causes the outside integral to vanish. Is that right?

Comment: @HankScorpio Easier is to use Fubini's Theorem, and reverse the order of integration.

Comment: Oh, right, silly me. Thanks for the answer and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that if this is for an undergraduate course, "holomorphic" means "holomorphic function in one variable".

My guess is they are asking whether it is possible for $\exp{(\frac{1}{zw})}$ to be written as $f(z)+g(w)$, where both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic except at $0$.

This question is, of course, a lot easier. Suppose there were such an example of $f,g$. Then immediately $(f-g)$ is a constant function and $2f(z)=\exp{(\frac{1}{z^2})}+C$, which doesn't work.

$\\$

If $f$ and $g$ are each meant to be holomorphic in two variables... yes, the answer to that question just pops out if you compare the Laurent series for $f$, $g$ and $\exp{(\frac{1}{zw})}$.

(See Section 2.7 of https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.j.o.o.wiegerinck/edu/scv/scv1.pdf)

But this is far, far beyond any undergraduate syllabus.

Comment: No, it really does say $g$ holomorphic on $\Bbb C^2\setminus \{z=0\}$ and similarly for $h$. I shortened the wording slightly when I wrote the problem in the post.

Comment: I can tell you that fourth-years at Oxford and Cambridge don't have multivariable complex analysis in their syllabus. Your course must be rather tough!

Comment: As I explained in the post, this is from supplementary material for a previous year's course taught by a professor who was known for being particularly tough. The instructors I'm working with and I don't really think it's pedagogically appropriate to use this for the current course, but I was curious to know the answer anyways, hence posting here.

Comment: I see. Anyway, just so that my answer is clear: your instinct that "by looking at negative-degree terms in z and w we ought to reach a contradiction" is correct. There is literally a theorem which says that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ minus the hyperplanes $\{z=0\}\cup\{w=0\}$, then $f$ is uniquely represented by a Laurent series in two variables. That is what I linked.